# custom UITextField with image as a background blinking cursor issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I have a custom UITextField with a UIImage as a background. Now when I type in a text into this UITextField and the cursor is blinking I get this:
[image]

I don't want to have a white image on the cursor blinking as it destroys the aesthetics.
I tried playing around with this and tried setting the background view to have the same color as the image, however the issue is that the UITextField shape is always a rectangle. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`?

You can use a UIImageView for the image and then add a UITextField as a subview with clear background. Just create `UIImageView *imageView` and `UITextField *textField`, either programmatically or in the IB. If you go programmatically, use `[imageView addSubview:textField];` and set the frame as you like. In the IB, just drop the `textField` onto the `imageView` and align it as you like.

Comment: yes I did try that and I still get the white background. How do I go about going with the second option? Mind showing some code?

Comment: I can't seem to drop the textField on the imageView on IB

Comment: also I tried adding the subview programatically, but it didn't work out as I didn't see any UITextField inside the UIImage, I tried bringSubviewIntoFront but it didn't work as well.. please suggest

Comment: @adit did this answer solve the problem then, or not?  You've accepted, but from your comments it seems the problem is not solved.  I have a very similar issue and would appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it. It does not have the cursor highlighted like that.

set

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor] // or your color
```

and

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

For adding the textField into the UIView ;

```
//Do this where you create the UIView* view


    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // or any other color

    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.delegate = self;


    [view addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: but the shape of the UITextField now is a rectangle and it doesn't have the shape of my UIImage

Comment: I have added the code for including the textfield in the the UIview

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `UIImageView` with your image in it, and then embedding a borderless `UITextField` inside your image view?  The text field will still be editable, but shouldn't interfere with the imageview behind it.