# adding UITextField to UIImageView layout issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom UITextField with image as a background blinking cursor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232434/custom-uitextfield-with-image-as-a-background-blinking-cursor-issue)

I have a UIImageView (the image has a pattern, gradient, and shadow in it). I have added a UITextField as a subview of this UIImageView and set the textField background to clear so that it's seen through, the code is:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 12, 359 , 36)];
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.placeholder = @"USERNAME";
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [username_background addSubview:textField];
```

The issue is that when I start editing the UITextField, I got the following layout issues:

Before editing:

[image]

When editing:

[image][image]

I can fix this if I change the UIColor clearColor background to some other color, but apparently I find difficulties getting the appropriate color for the background. I did try doing:

```
 [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkg-username.png"]];
```

However, what I am getting is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the UITextField as a subview on the view of the viewcontroller, and not the 'username_background' UIImageView. I believe this should fix your problem.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to build this view?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new image to use as the background that consists of only the pattern in the center of the original image (no gradients or corners).

Comment: I know this will fix it, but I am looking for a different way than this

Comment: actually it won't, it won't solve the problem of copy and pasting as shown above.. it still has that white text space